# How to add CSV Import/Export Functionality

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1, import, export, csv

I have created custom gallery extension but I need to implement an *import* and *export* or gallery data in the CSV Format.

I did too much research but couldn't find any useful link to find solution so please let me know if anybody had idea for this.

Comment: more details are helpful. Do you use the catalog_product_gallery functionality or your own database? Do you just want the data?

Comment: Alex's solution below is the answer - please mark as accepted.

Answer (score 4):

For a CSV exports you can generate a grid with your data and use the `getCsv()` function. Sounds overhead, but that's exactly what the export of the Tablerates shipping cost table in the backend does.

See: `Mage_Adminhtml_System_ConfigController::exportTableratesAction` and `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Shipping_Carrier_Tablerate_Grid`.

For the import you could also have a look at this module (`Mage_Shipping_Model_Resource_Carrier_Tablerate::uploadAndImport`) or on the import module for product data (`Mage_ImportExport`), but this is much more complicated.

Comment: Can you please mark this answer as your solution, or do you have unaswered problems?